# Pass AWS credentials (IAM role credentials) to code running in Docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam

When running code on an EC2 instance, the SDK I use to access AWS resources, automagically talks to a locally linked web server on `169.254.169.254` and gets that instances AWS credentials (access_key, secret) that are needed to talk to other AWS services.

Also there are other options, like setting the credentials in environment variables or passing them as command line args.

What is the best practice here? I really prefer to let the container access the `169.254.169.254` (by routing the requests) or even better run a proxy container that mimics the behavior of the real server at `169.254.169.254`.

Is there already a solution out there?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78146880/1374730) is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The EC2 metadata service will usually be available from within docker (unless you use a more custom networking setup - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411611/1027148) on a similar question).

If your docker network setup prevents it from being accessed, you might use the `ENV` directive in your `Dockerfile` or pass them directly during run, but keep in mind that credentials from IAM roles are automatically rotated by AWS.

Comment: mmm, so I guess my misunderstanding come from my experimentation with boot2docker (on mac) where networking in awkward or at least different. So basically things should just work. mmmm I need to try this.

Comment: The one issue I have with this architecture (let AWS SDK/CLI within the container hit the EC2 metadata endpoint for credentials) is that I want a fine-grain control over what permissions a container will have. One container might only be able to write to S3, whilst other I might want to not have any S3 permissions, and instead just let it publish to SNS. This design would mean that I need to add superset of permissions to EC2, and all my containers would have the same.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk - that is where ECS comes in. You can assign a role to an ECS service

Answer (score 4):

Amazon does have some mechanisms for allowing containers to access IAM roles via the SDK and either routing/forwarding requests through the ECS agent container or the host. There is way too much to copy and paste, but using `--net host` is the LEAST recommended option because without additionally filters that allows your container full access to anything it's host has permission to do.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

```
declare -a ENVVARS
declare AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
get_aws_creds_local () {
   # Use this to get secrets on a non AWS host assuming you've set credentials via some mechanism in the past, and then don't pass in a profile to gitlab-runner because it doesn't see the ~/.aws/credentials file where it would look up profiles
   awsProfile=${AWS_PROFILE:-default}
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws --profile $awsProfile configure get aws_access_key_id)
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws --profile $awsProfile configure get aws_secret_access_key)
   AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(aws --profile $awsProfile configure get aws_session_token)
   
}

get_aws_creds_iam () {
  TEMP_ROLE=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/example-role" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session)
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $TEMP_ROLE | jq -r . Credentials.RoleAccessKeyID)
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $TEMP_ROLE | jq -r . Credentials.RoleSecretKey)
  AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $TEMP_ROLE | jq -r . Credentials.RoleSessionToken)
}

get_aws_creds_local

get_aws_creds_iam

ENVVARS=("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCESS_KEY_ID" "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$ACCESS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN")

# passing creds into GitLab runner
 gitlab-runner exec docker stepName $(printf " --env %s" "${ENVVARS[@]}")

# using creds with a docker container
docker run -it --rm $(printf " --env %s" "${ENVVARS[@]}") amazon/aws-cli sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: can you give a small example where I should put `--net host` part?

Comment: Anywhere after `docker run` and before the container name you are running like `ubuntu` or `redis`.

Comment: I am using `docker-in-docker` so in that case, does this going to work?

Comment: These are the two links I used to set up the runner, I'll add the lines of code that enable passing in the credentials shortly. https://gist.github.com/adamstraube/b5c8eae3034f3d8d5561cfb143751d7e#gistcomment-3350289  https://adamstraube.github.io/using-gitlab-runner-locally-with-docker-in-docker-on-windows-10-and-wsl/

Comment: I don't have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` or anything. But I only have access to one of the EC2 instances in that AWS account, so I don't have to use any of those credentials. I am not authorized to create new users or new tokens or anything. When I use `gitlab runner` `shell` executor it works fine. But the problem is with the `docker` executor now.

Comment: If you run `aws get-caller-identity` under the shell runner it may give you an identity that you can use as the `TEMP_ROLE`. If you run the docker command from the bottom without the printf block does it show an identity.

Comment: @dragon788 `aws sts get-caller-identity`