# IAM Role + Boto3 + Docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, boto3

As far I as I know, boto3 will try to load credentials from the instance metadata service.
If I am running this code inside a EC2 instance I expected to hae no problem. But when my code is dockerized how the boto3 will find the metadata service?

Comment: Crazy that I just googled this and a 2-hour-old question shows up 2nd. Anyway there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911000/pass-aws-credentials-iam-role-credentials-to-code-running-in-docker-container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching AWS instance metadata from within Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409367/fetching-aws-instance-metadata-from-within-docker-container)

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon ECS agent populates the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` environment variable which can be used to get credentials. These special variables are provided only to process with PID 1. Script that is specified in Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` gets PID 1.

There are many networking modes and details might differ for other networking modes. More information can be found in: [How can I configure IAM task roles in Amazon ECS to avoid "Access Denied" errors?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-iam-task-roles-config-errors/)

For `awsvpc` networking mode If you would run `printenv` with PID 1 you would see something similar to this:

```
AWS_EXECUTION_ENV=AWS_ECS_FARGATE                                                                                                                                        
AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=/v2/credentials/0f891318-ab05-46fe-8fac-d5113a1c2ecd                                                                              
HOSTNAME=ip-172-17-0-123.ap-south-1.compute.internal                                                                                                                     
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-south-1                                                                                                                                            
AWS_REGION=ap-south-1                                                                                                                                                    
ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4=http://169.254.170.2/v4/2c9107c385e04a70b30d3cc4d4de97e7-527074092                                                                         
ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI=http://169.254.170.2/v3/2c9107c385e04a70b30d3cc4d4de97e7-527074092
```

It also gets tricky to debug something since after SSH'ing into container you are using PID other than 1 meaning that services that need to get credentials might fail to do so if you run them manually.

ECS task metadata endpoint [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html)

Answer (score -3):

Find .aws folder in ~/.aws in your machine and move this to Docker container's /root folder.

.aws contains files which has AWS KEY and AWS PW. 
You can easily copy it to currently running container from your local machine by
`docker cp ~/.aws <containder_id>:/root`

Comment: The files in .aws on the EC2 will not exist unless you specifically put them there. That's not what the question was about.