# How to pass AWS IAM Role to a docker-in-docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have an `EC2` instance. It has a `python` snippet to put some data on the `s3` bucket. I have attached the `S3` full admin role to this `EC2` machine and it works fine. Great.

And then I wanted to run the same `python` script inside `Docker`

So I installed `docker` and executed the `python` script.

And now I get the error message saying it doesn't have access to `S3` resources.

So the problem is, `docker` network and `EC2`/Host network are different, right?!?

So I googled and found this:

```
--net host
```

But how can I set this command and make the docker-in-docker looks like it is in the same network as it's host?

Where should I supposed to put this `--net host` part?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376444/1190388

Comment: I don't use `AWS` credentials at all, because `EC2` instance is already in the `AWS`. I have even used terraform like this. Spin up an `Ec2` instance and put some `terraform` code in their and `terraform apply` will execute without any problem since I the `Ec2` is already in the same `vpc` and all.

Comment: have you tried to access the meta data url from inside the docker. can you ssh into the docker container and run `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/[your role name]`.

Comment: Can you also make sure that the container does not have a `.aws` directory in case if the aws cli is looking for the credentials in the wrong place. you can also pass a `--debug` option to the `aws` cli command for e.g `aws --debug s3 ls`. it could hint you where the problem is.

Comment: You need to start the docker container in host mode. An example command would be, `docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx`

Comment: since I have using `docker-in`docker` I need to add `DOCKER HOST` as well. But this time the host is `didd` no the actual host.

Answer (score 2):

Move your docker application from standalone EC2 to AWS ECS there you can attach IAM role to container which simplifies work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to do that, first I need to check this