# Is it possible to get host details from within docker container?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to get host's info from within docker, for example

1. HOST Machine's IP (eth0's IP not docker0's)
2. Available RAM in HOST machine

etc.,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

It's not generally possible - it would break the isolation which Docker provides.

In this article, you can see how, any breakout from the Docker container is actually a serious security issue.

https://blog.docker.com/2014/06/docker-container-breakout-proof-of-concept-exploit/

**However**, there are various workarounds:

http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2014/06/accessing-the-docker-host-server-within-a-container/

Suggests that the following approach:

> "Although there’s no way to introspect the host’s ip address (AFAIK) you can pass this in via an environment variable:"

```
docker@boot2docker:~$  docker run -i -t -e DOCKER_HOST=192.168.59.103 ubuntu /bin/bash
root@07561b0607f4:/# env
HOSTNAME=07561b0607f4
DOCKER_HOST=192.168.59.103
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
```

On EC2, specifically, you can access the instance's metadata:

See

[Fetching AWS instance metadata from within Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409367/fetching-aws-instance-metadata-from-within-docker-container)

In particular:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname
ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Other metadata options are listed here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Thank you, Donald
I'm currently using the same method on EC2. `docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e HOST_IP=$(hostname --ip-address) shan/elk:latest`
My use case is, I'm running elasticsearch inside docker and i need to pass the IP of the host machine to `network.publish_host:` parameter in elasticsearch
Without passing the HOST_IP, auto discovery is not working
Thank you very much Donald.

Comment: I'm afraid you have'll to pass it in - it's just not possible to break out of the container otherwise.

Comment: Have to live with it, as security is more important

Comment: Donald's answer is true in general, but on EC2, you could query instance metadata to get the IP address.

Comment: Thanks both of you @Donald_W  and @NathanielWaisbrot, it working fine. I'm able to get the instance IP using `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`.