# Detect AWS host environment from within a Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, containers

From within a Docker container, how can I detect that I am running inside an AWS environment? I want the same container to optionally execute some AWS commands on startup *IF* running from within AWS, but skip those if running in a local environment.

Currently, I am thinking that the simple way is to set an environment variable when running in AWS.

Is there another way?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409367/fetching-aws-instance-metadata-from-within-docker-container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Docker container lacks **curl** or **wget**, you may use this trick in Bash:

```
if ( exec 2>/dev/null ; echo > /dev/tcp/169.254.169.254/80 ) ; then
   echo "AWS"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
curl -i http://169.254.169.254/ | grep "200 OK"
```

Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/identify_ec2_instances.html

Answer (score 1):

Crude way of checking if you are running on AWS. All instances that are running on AWS have access to an internal metadata server with IP: `169.254.169.254`. If you can connect to it, then you are on AWS. Otherwise you are not.

```
$ curl -s --connect-timeout 2 169.254.169.254 > /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

On non AWS machine:

```
$ curl -s --connect-timeout 2 169.254.169.254 > /dev/null
$ echo $?
28
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you!