# How to assume AWS role in docker container run on Elasticbeanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, boto3

I use elasticbeanstalk with multicontainer version and I have docker container with boto3 inside. I would like to assume role to save files on S3 using python.

Based on this question: [Fetching AWS instance metadata from within Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409367/fetching-aws-instance-metadata-from-within-docker-container/22411611#22411611)

`urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/instance-id-credentials/s3access').read().decode('utf-8')`

returns 404.

I don't want use hardcoded credentials in my docker image.
Is there a way to somehow assume role?

Comment: Have you read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-servicerole.html

Comment: Yeap, which header do you mind?

Answer (score 1):

I made this work by starting the container in `--net host` mode. I.e. use the host's networking stack to make AWS think that you are requesting from the EC2 host.

This was the comment that provided this solution: [Fetching AWS instance metadata from within Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409367/fetching-aws-instance-metadata-from-within-docker-container?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment80583218_22411611)