# botocore.exceptions.InvalidConfigError: The source profile "default" must have credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3

The code below fails in row `s3 = boto3.client('s3')` returning error `botocore.exceptions.InvalidConfigError: The source profile "default" must have credentials.`

```
def connect_s3_boto3():
    try:
        os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"] = "a"
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        return s3
    except:
        raise
```

I have set up the key and secret using `aws configure`
[image]

My file `vim ~/.aws/credentials` looks like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

My file `vim ~/.aws/config` looks like:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json

[profile b]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::XX
source_profile=default

[profile a]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::YY
source_profile=default

[profile d]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::EE
source_profile=default
```

If I run `aws-vault exec --no-session --debug a`
it returns:

`aws-vault: error: exec: Failed to get credentials for a9e: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
        status code: 403, request id: 7087ea72-32c5-4b0a-a20e-fd2da9c3c747`

Comment: What happens when you remove the line: os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"] = "a"?

Comment: Does the AWS CLI work from the same system?

Comment: Shouldn't there be matching `[a]` in `~/.aws/credentials` as well?

Comment: @JamesShapiro it returns botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Comment: Let's start with something simple. Can you use the AWS CLI with the `[default]` profile? For example: `aws s3 ls` (with nothing in the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, I can do it, and I see the content

Comment: Excellent. This means that the credentials file is setup correctly. Next, from the same system that you just used with `aws s3 ls`, try running a Python program to list the buckets (_without_ changing the profile). So, it should use `s3 = boto3.client('s3')` and then `response = s3.list_buckets()`. That should return a list of buckets.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it works. It returns a list of objects with name and creationDate

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are trying to accomplish (eg I don't know why you included `aws-vault` output), but it looks like you are wanting to access S3 resources via  role. You can follow advice from [Credentials — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) and add lines like: `session = boto3.Session(profile_name='a')` and `s3_client = session.client('s3')`. This should then let you use that `s3_client` to access resources through the role.

Comment: I run all this script in a docker container. If I run it in a conda environment it works, because it uses the aws configure that i set up in local. Now that I have moved it to a docker it doesn't work, despite I run all the statements u tell me in the docker through bash.

I also tried to do aws configure and add the same working key and secret that I have in local.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while trying to assume a role on an ECS container. It turned out that in such cases, instead of `source_profile`, `credential_source` should be used. It takes the value of `EcsContainer` for the container, `Ec2InstanceMetadata` for the EC2 machine or `Environment` for other cases.

Since the solution is not very intuitive, I thought it might save someone the trouble despite the age of this question.

Comment: Just had the same problem on Fargate. `credential_source = EcsContainer` saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you tagged this question with "docker". Is it possible that you're running your code from a Docker container that does not have your AWS credentials in it?

Comment: Yes, I run it from a docker container but I do `docker exec -it name bash` so every statement I run is inside the docker

Comment: Yeah, but it looks like your credentials are not accessible from your container. What happens when you run "aws s3 ls" from inside of your Docker container?

Comment: it says credentials are not there, but if i run aws configure then it works. If after that I retry it, it still failing...

Comment: It should automatically work as in local as I understand from that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409367/fetching-aws-instance-metadata-from-within-docker-container/22411611#22411611

Comment: It sounds like when you "retry" it, you are clearing away your credentials, so every time you retry it it will fail. The question you linked to does not seem relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a docker volume to pass your credential files into the container:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

It is not a good idea to add credentials into a container image because anybody who uses this image will have and use **your** credentials.
This is considered a bad practice.

For more information how to properly deal with secrets see https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Answer (score -3):

Finally the issue is that Docker didn't had the credentials. And despite connect through bash and add them, it didn't work.

So, in the `dockerfile` I added:

```
ADD myfolder/aws/credentials /root/.aws/credentials
```

To move my locahost credentials files added through `aws cli` using `aws configure` to the docker. Then, I build the docker again and it works.

Comment: This is a security anti-pattern. Never under any circumstances should you do this, ever.